# ModuleNotFoundError Despite being Installed

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I'm having trouble loading a package that is installed in my environment and have no idea why..

```
conda list
fbprophet                 0.3.post2                py36_0    conda-forge
```

When I request for libraries installed in **conda**, it clearly shows that I have **fbprophet** installed. Now, when I import it, a ModuleNotFoundError exception is thrown.

```
    from fbprophet import Prophet
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-83be6864a7aa> in <module>()
----> 1 from fbprophet import Prophet
      2 import numpy as np
      3 import pandas as pd

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fbprophet'
```

Has anybody run into this issue? What can I do to troubleshoot this?

Comment: You may have more than one Python installation. Thus you might installed the library in one Python installation and tried to call it from another one. Please let me know if you have more than one Python installation by printing the result os this CMD command **where python**.

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56451612/10669875)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be creating a virtual environment for your python first, then conda install your package in the virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

My script was reading from my pip install list where the module fbprophet did not exist. I went back and installed it there and everything worked. Lesson learned.

Always check where your libraries are being read from.

Answer (score 0):

You may have more than one Python installation. Thus you might installed the library in one Python installation and tried to call it from another one. Please let me know if you have more than one Python installation by printing the result os this CMD command **where python**.