# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'docx' on VScode but not in Python itself

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pip, python-docx

I have installed the python-docx module using pip:

```
python -m pip install python-docx
```

However, when I try to run my script that only contains `import docx`, I get the following error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'docx'
```

When I execute the following command in Python on the command line, it works fine:

```py
import docx
```

Comment: Does the top line of your script start with something like: `#!/usr/bin/env python`? Such a "shebang" expression will override the location of the Python used to run the script. In any case, it sounds like you have at least two Python installations and your script uses a different one than the command-line. Not docx-related per-se.

Comment: theres no "shebang".
How can i check the instalations of python i have ?
As far as i can remember i just installed it once.

Comment: import sys

print(sys.version)
3.7.0 (default, Jun 28 2018, 08:04:48) [MSC v.1912 64 bit (AMD64)]

in cmd i get:
python --version
Python 3.7.1

Answer (score 0):

When using Visual Studio Code, make sure that it uses the same Python version as you are using when running the script. You you should set the "python.pythonPath" setting correctly in `settings.json` (manually edit the file or edit in Visual Studio itself). This can be done system-wide (per user), or per project.

Furthermore, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56451612/10669875) gives some background about how Python files are executed in Windows.