# how to fix install of requests library?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-requests

I am learning Python, using Windows and Vs Code editor.
My .py simply contains :  import requests
and I see  this error  **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'**
I think the library is installed because :
Pip freeze shows :  **requests==2.22.0**
pip install requests shows : Requirement already satisfied: requests in d:\python\lib\site-packages (2.22.0)

What am I missing?
Thanks,Peter

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56451612/10669875) help you?

Answer (score 1):

It's likely you're using a python version that it's in a different location, do you have multiple versions of Python installed?

One easy way to see what packages you're using on that version of python is to do

```
>>> import site
>>> site.getsitepackages()
```

It's generally a good idea to use [virtual environments](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/) for Python to help with that kind of package control

Comment: Good tip.  I found a good wiki on virtualenv :  https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/#virtualenvironments-ref