# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yfinance', what can I do on Mac, using VC

Tags: python, yfinance

So I currently am trying to use yfinance in Visual Studio Code on Mac. I downloaded pip through 'sudo easy_install pip' and downloaded yfinance via pip install. When I try to run my code I get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yfinance'. What can I do??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio' (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56449253/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pyaudio-windows)

Comment: you remembered to import it?
and also when you pip installed it, it was a successful install?

Could you share code?

Comment: I know the above question/answer is mostly about Windows and you asked about Mac, but a part of the information will be true for both platforms and might answer your question.

Comment: I think there must be some problem with the module you are importing. can you please add your import code. there may some spelling issues or something

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio will be running a different instance of python to the rest of your system if you did your pip install using the Mac Terminal, it would probably have installed it for a different instance. You'll have to either issue the command in VS (In windows, it's under Tools > Command line) or you'll have to specify that instance in you command from the terminal.