# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'result'

Tags: python, jupyter

Let me know how to solve this error regarding 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'results''.

-best_score.py code example

```
   #!/usr/bin/env python3
   #
   # Count the number of fitting results available.
   #
   #
   import numpy as np
   import os
   import sys

    # Load project modules
     sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('python'))
     import results
     import transformations
```

-Error Example

```
   ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
   <ipython-input-1-656f534a7811> in <module>
    10 # Load project modules
    11 sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('python'))
    ---> 12 import results
    13 import transformations
    14 

   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'results'
```

Comment: Well, do you _have_ a `results.py` module?

Comment: Or are you trying to use [this pip module](https://pypi.org/project/results/)

Comment: I already installed package -results'. But It occurs same error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio' (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56449253/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pyaudio-windows)

Answer (score 1):

Go to your terminal and do 'pip install results'. Check the settings to see if it is added to the interpreter.

Comment: I already installed package -results'. But It occurs same error.

Comment: Why don't you import results at the top of the page? Why is it under sys.path.appends? Put all the import statements at the top