# rasa_nlu error while creating small chatbot

Tags: python, chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa

Iam getting the below error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rasa_nlu', even though i installed rasa_nlu and rasa

My code :

```
from rasa_nlu.training_data import load_data
from rasa_nlu.config import RasaNLUConfig
from rasa_nlu.model import Trainer

def train_nlu(data, config, model_dir):
    training_data = load_data(data)
    trainer = Trainer(RasaNLUConfig(config))
    trainer.train(training_data)
    model_directory = trainer.persist(model_dir, fixed_model_name='weathernlu')
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    train_nlu('.data/data.json', 'config_spacy.json', './models/nlu')
```

Error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-6ab2834ad68f> in <module>()
----> 1 from rasa_nlu.training_data import load_data
      2 #from rasa_nlu.converters import load_data
      3 from rasa_nlu.config import RasaNLUConfig
      4 from rasa_nlu.model import Trainer
      5 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rasa_nlu'
```

Someone please help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio' (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56449253/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pyaudio-windows)

Answer (score 0):

In Rasa >= 1.0, there is no separate installation of NLU. It's just `rasa`, and then in code you'd access `rasa.nlu`. Make sure you're looking at the latest version of the docs and have installed the latest version of rasa - https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/user-guide/installation/

Comment: Please elaborate in your question what you are trying now and what isn't working. If it is still showing `No module named 'rasa_nlu'`, that's because you're still referencing `rasa_nlu`, which you shouldn't be.