# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.util'

Tags: python

Getting error,  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named **'tensorflow.python.util**

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling more than 10 times, and tried different variations
pip install tensorflow_gpu, pip install tensorflow --user, and also upgraded my pip.
But still this error keeps happening when I try to import keras.models from tensorflow to run a model.

Does anyone know how to resolve the issue? Thanks in advance.

```
The full error I am getting:

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-114c1607a26b> in <module>
      4 from datetime import datetime
      5 import numpy as np
----> 6 from tensorflow import keras
      7 from keras.models import Sequential
      8 from keras.layers import LSTM

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>
     39 import sys as _sys
     40 
---> 41 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
     42 from tensorflow.python.util.lazy_loader import LazyLoader as _LazyLoader
     43 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>
     38 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import,g-bad-import-order,g-import-not-at-top
     39 
---> 40 from tensorflow.python.eager import context
     41 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
     42 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py in <module>
     34 from tensorflow.core.protobuf import rewriter_config_pb2
     35 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tfe
---> 36 from tensorflow.python import tf2
     37 from tensorflow.python.client import pywrap_tf_session
     38 from tensorflow.python.eager import executor

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\tf2.py in <module>
     24 
     25 from tensorflow.python.platform import _pywrap_tf2
---> 26 from tensorflow.python.util.tf_export import tf_export
     27 
     28
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.util

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio' (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56449253/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pyaudio-windows)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that pip is installing it for python 2 and then you are running in python 3. I have seen this behaviour and then needing to use pip3.