# Python not finding modules (tried with bs4 and selenium separately)

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have repeatedly installed and uninstalled `beautifulsoup4`, but no matter what I try to do, when I try to `import bs4` in shell, I get `ModuleNotFoundError`.

I'm on Windows 11 and using Python 3.10.7. I'm new to programming and learning from automatetheboringstuff.com, but have been all over the web trying to figure this out and have tried basically every variation of pip installation to get it on there.

When I run `pip show`, i can see that it's installed and located at:

```
c:\users\__\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages
```

and as far as I can tell that is where my python is running from. I am using mu editor and I feel like that might be the problem as it does not seem like any other person with similar problems uses that, but I don't know enough to confirm that.

Here is the full traceback: ModuleNotFoundError Traceback (most recent call last)  in () ----> 1 from bs4 import beautifulsoup ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you type `python -V`, does it actually show 3.10?

Comment: @TimRoberts It shows Python 3.10.7

Comment: Run `python -m pip install beautifulsoup4` instead of `pip install beautifulsoup4`.

Comment: I have also run python -m pip install beautifulsoup4 and have the same issue

Comment: Then [edit] your question and include the **exact** commands you used to install beautifulsoup, check the python version and run the scripts (and the output you get for those commands of course).

Comment: NB: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56451612/10669875) explains likely causes and solutions for this problem (by lack of more details, this question should probably be closed as duplicate). There are also more then [16000 others posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+ModulenotFoundError) about this error, of which [87 specifically about beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+modulenotfounderror+%5Bbeautifulsoup%5D).

Answer (score -1):

A **dirty and not recommended** way to make it work would be to temporarily install the package at the beginning of your script via:

```
import pip
pip.main(['install', 'beautifulsoup4'])

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup  # <-- this should work now
```

It's **dirty and not recommended** as you should **figure out what's wrong with your venv**.

Anyways, I posted this answer because I had the same issue as I started programming, just wanting to play around a bit and this **fixes it TEMPORARY**.

You should **NEVER DO THIS IN PRODUCTION ENVIRONMENT**.

**Instead**:

**Figure out what's wrong with your env!** Possible problem:

**Your script might run with a different interpreter.**
You can get the path of the used interpreter by writing at the start of your script:

```
import sys

print(sys.executable)
```

Make sure this is the same path where you installed the package.

**Check current interpreter:**
To check wether your package is installed in the current interpreter path, you can write e.g. this at the start of your script:

```
import pip

print(pip.main(['freeze']))
```

If your package isn't listed in the output, then you are using the false interpreter.

Comment: For ease of me being a dummy, I assume this is entered in the shell not the command prompt?

Comment: Yes, just the line before you do "import bs4". But as I wrote, it's dirty and not recommended as you should figure out what's wrong with your venv.

Comment: Indeed, dirty and not recommended. This will always try to install the module, slowing down your application and dumping a lot of output on your screen. Completely unnecessary. It will even print the following warning: "_WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip. Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue._"