# Why do I get "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip'" despite installing it with pip?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I get a "module not found" error when using idle while trying to import pyperclip.

In command terminal as administrator tried to install pyperclip using:

```
pip install pyperclip
```

Output was:

> Requirement already satisfied: pyperclip in c:\users\ john smith\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (1.8.2)

I previously had anaconda navigator and jupyter notebook. I could import pyperclip in jupyter notebook. I deleted anaconda to try and see if it was because I had pyperclip installed in only location, but it did not solve the problem.

So where can I go from here?

edit :

I uninstalled python 3.7, as i had both 3.7 32 bit  and 3.9 64 bit installed,

i ran the command : pip install pyperclip again in command

output :

Requirement already satisfied: pyperclip in c:\users\ john smith\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (1.8.2)

module still not found

edit: problem solved

- went into the script for 3.9 and opened a cmd terminal
- installed pip from there
- thank you for your responses

Comment: Where, exactly, are you trying to import pyperclip?  The UIs usually have their own Python installations, separate from the one at your command line.  You need to install the module in the version of Python you are running.

Comment: Perhaps pyperclip is installed, just not in the environment that happens to be active when you are running your script (which may just be the global environment for whatever version of Python the script happens to be executed with). How are you running the script?

Comment: @Grismar 
i entered this command : py -0p

output was : Installed Pythons found by py Launcher for Windows
 -3.9-64        python3.9.exe *
 -3.7-32        C:\Users\jon smith\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe
does this mean that i have two environments in which pyperclip is only installed in 1, if so how would i go about installing pyperclip in both, thank you for your response

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio' (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56449253/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pyaudio-windows)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you're running two version of Python on your machine. Ex. a 2.7 and a 3.10. If you're on Windows, you can run the command `py -0p` to list all your python versions and their paths.

If you're looking to install pyperclip for a 3+ version of Python, you might want to use pip3 to install it.

Comment: hi, i ran this command first  : py -0p
Installed Pythons found by py Launcher for Windows
 -3.9-64        python3.9.exe *
 -3.7-32        C:\Users\jon smith\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe        and then ran this command : pip3 install pyperclip


Requirement already satisfied: pyperclip in c:\users\jon smith\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (1.8.2)

what does this mean? and how do i move forward with it ? thank you for your response

Comment: This  Python  `C:\Users\jon smith\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe` is a 32-bit installation of Python 3.7. But your `py` invocation is from a 64-bit installation of Python 3.9. So you clearly have at least 2 Python installatoins. Do `pip --version` to find out which one `pip` is installing to. If it isn't the installation that is giving you the import error, then you need to run a different `pip`, not tho one that is first on your `PATH`. The one you need is in the `scripts` folder of your intended install target installation.