# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame_menu'

Tags: python, pip, pygame-menu

I'm trying to make a game using `pygame` and `pygame_menu`. When I try to install `pygame_menu` I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Game\main.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pygame_menu
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame_menu'
```

I ran this command to install the module:
`pip install pygame-menu -U`

Here's how I import the module:
`import pygame_menu`

I have no idea how to fix this. If you know how to fix this or a better module for GUI elements in pygame please tell me.

Comment: installing and importing the module as you mentioned works perfectly for me. Maybe you installed the module in a different virtual environment?

Comment: @storageSpaceFull I'm using pycharm. Could that be a problem?

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56449253/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named

Comment: @kadis Thank you. That did indeed help me install the package.

Answer (score -2):

I'm far from experienced in PyGame and pygame-menu, but I'm able to get a window up and running with the following code and importing both pygame and pygame-menu with the following commands:

`pip install pygame`

`pip install pygame-menu -U`

```
import pygame
import pygame_menu

pygame.init()
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 400))

menu = pygame_menu.Menu('Welcome', 400, 300,
                   theme=pygame_menu.themes.THEME_BLUE)

menu.add.label('Hello World!')

menu.mainloop(surface)
```

Please try this code above to see if you can get it working.

Comment: I'm having issues with the installation and importing of pygame_menu not using it (as of yet at least lol)

Answer (score -2):

[Install instructions](https://pypi.org/project/pygame-menu/#:%7E:text=Pygame%2Dmenu%20is%20a%20python,with%20multiple%20options%20to%20customize.)

These are the install instructions. Follow these to install pygame-menu.
Once you've done that, import by using `import pygame_menu`

Comment: That's what I tried. It didn't work. Besides, the question is already solved