# Scrapy crawl return ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_lzma'

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, playwright-python

I am currently experiencing a problem when trying to run a scrapy crawl in my dedicated virtual environment. Indeed it returns me the error quoted in the title of this topic.

So I start by checking the version of python.

[image: Checking python version]

And then creates the virtual work environment.

[image]

Cheks if the directory is present.

[image]

Take a look at `pip list` just to be sure.

[image]

I continue with `pip install scrapy playwright`

[image]

I finally check if scrapy works properly with `scrapy bench` which return me :

[image]

So i first tried to install liblzma-dev and backports.lzma with

```
sudo apt-get install liblzma-dev
```

[image]

```
pip install backports.lzma
```

[image]

Which still end up returning

[image]

Does anyone have a solution to this problem please?

Comment: does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56449253/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named

Comment: @kadis no but it's nice to have tried I checked and all the path are well informed and give me a version of python 3.10.2

Comment: did you try `sudo apt install python3-scrapy`?  Does scrapy work as sudo?

Comment: just try it and still return the _lzma error :/ thx anyway@Alexander

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I don't know why but after completely uninstalling scrapy from my computer and reinstalling it only in the env it worked.

Knowing that I already had scrapy installed outside venv and it worked perfectly.

edit :

Ok so after trying to recreate the bug, you will be happy to know that I succeeded :)

The only drawback is that unlike before, I can't fix it despite having reproduced the exact same steps :$

Does anyone have an idea?  Because I'm going in circles...

Comment: You can accept this as the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @Brian No I can't because after deleting the virtual environment and restarting all the manipulations I find myself back at the starting point with this ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_lzma' and I don't really understand why :/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).