# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pafy'

Tags: python, pytube, pafy

I downloaded the buffy library using pip install pafy
and when I run the code,
`

```
import pafy
url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bMt47wvK6u0"
video = pafy.new(url)
streams = video.streams
print("hello")
for s in streams:
    print(s)
```

this problem appears

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\habdn\OneDrive\المستندات\Downloader\import pafy.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pafy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pafy'
```

my python version is 12.0 and last version of pip
please can any one help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '...'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56449253/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named)